# Google OAuth 2.0 + Service Account Access + Subset of users always fail with invalid_grant

Tags: google-oauth

I am requesting tokens for accessing imap data from user accounts using a service account.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Now most users validate fine and I receive a token that I can reuse for 3600 seconds.  That is fine.  Some of the users, however, fail every time with "invalid_grant".  I am at a loss as to why the same library, the same apiclient, and the same signing key result in this behavior.

Again an unchanging subset of the users always fail with "invalid_grant".

Any ideas?

Comment: are these invalid grant users under the same domain as the valid users?

Comment: They have the same domain in their email address.  In terms of how they are organized within the company, I am not sure.  I migrated away  from Oauth 1.0 with the hope that would solve the issue, but it persists.